# Add style to pseudo element

Tags: html, css

How to add style to to pseudo element. I want to give a width:40% to first element.

```
<div class="nav-bar">
      <div class="menu-bar">
          <div class="menu-toggle">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.menu-bar {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0.8em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-toggle, .menu-toggle::after, .menu-toggle::before{
 content: '';
 display: block;
 width: 2em;
 height: 2px;
}
```

I tried but its not working.

```
.menu-bar:hover:after{
 width: 40%;
}

.menu-bar:hover .menu-toggle::after{
 width: 40%;
}

.menu-bar:hover::after{
 width: 40%;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you want to give a style to the first element, use `first-child`

Comment: And if you just want to give `width:40%` to `.menu-bar`, why not just use `.menu-bar{width:40%}`?

Comment: no jquery involve only css will remove jquery tag

Comment: No, I mean i want to give style to first element only which is `.menu-toggle::after` a width of 40% when the menu-bar is hovered.